# xbox smf player change template

Tags: silverlight-3.0, expression-blend, xbox360, smf

I need to change the default UI of SMF player on xbox 360. I have this SMF player from the reference application that comes with xbox ADK from Novermber 2012. But I don't know template parts names, required for the player, and I had no success to do it in Blend Studio (it throws exceptions, because of specific xbox 360 environment). Has anybody done it before? Any tips?

Comment: Tell us what you have tried. Show some code and describe your problem with it.

Comment: Hi Ari, I don't have really much code for that. All what I have is just '<smf:SMFPlayer Template="{StaticResource SMFTemplate}"></smf:SMFPlayer>'. I need to set up "SMFTemplate" in order to provide custom control buttons for the player. But I don't know any template parts. And as it is xbox project I have an errors in blend when I try to open SMFPlayer in there. Maybe you know an example or such a template definition. Thanks!

Comment: If you knowns nothing about system you are writing for, start with some tutorial or sth. Otherwise you should be able to produce some code doing sth near to what you need

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I know how to change template for different control (because it has docs about that and it works for me in Blend Studio). But the control I am talking about is SMFPlayer and it has no documentation in that area. In order to change its style - I need to know the default style for this control. So the question is how to change template for SMFPlayer control? Which template parts (the required parts to be provided in new control template) this control has?